# Keep tense in harmony, or not?

Tags: tense-agreement

Suppose you're having a conversation with someone, and you're intrigued as to which college they go to. So, you ask them that, and they say X. At this point, if you wished to express how surprised you are, which one of the two would you use:

> I didn't know/I had no idea you **went** to X.

Or, would you use:

> I didn't know/I had no idea you **go** to X.

I suppose both are grammatically correct.
What's the difference in their meaning?

In similar cases, and this one, is it better to keep the tenses in harmony?

Comment: Backshift to **went** referring to the present is common, and I would venture to say it's a little more common than simple present after "I didn't know", at least in the English I hear spoken on a daily basis.  "I didn't know that piece of the puzzle went there!" versus "I didn't know that piece of the puzzle goes there!"  There are two times involved: past ignorance and timeless fact.  Whether things change when the timeless fact is expressed in the past or the present is debatable.

Comment: *I didn't know you had a twin sister!*  [could be spoken even as the speaker learns about the twin by seeing the two together]

Comment: What about generalizations?
Did you know the sun set/sets in the west? @TRomano

Comment: Generalizations tend to be stated in the present.  *Did you know that raisins make a dog sick?* But *I never knew that raisins made a dog sick!*